# cancelAllLocalNotifications not working in iOS10

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, ios10

I want to remove all previous local notification from NotificationCenter  when adding new notifications. But it is working in iOS9.0 and lower version but in iOS 10 it fires multiple local notifications. So it seems like `cancelAllLocalNotifications` not clearing notifications.

Code compile successfully in iOS10.

```
UIApplication.shared.cancelAllLocalNotifications()
```

Comment: for iOS10 notifications, what you are using? are you using "UserNotifications" framework ?

Comment: Yes, I am using `UNUserNotifications` framework

Comment: Interesting, `cancelAllLocalNotifications()` is working for me in iOS 10.2.

Comment: `cancelAllLocalNotifications()` worked for me until I linked the iOS 10's UserNotification's framework. With that linked I can post local notifications with the old API but the cancel all stopped working.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For iOS 10, Swift 3.0

`cancelAllLocalNotifications` deprecated from iOS 10.

> ```
> @available(iOS, introduced: 4.0, deprecated: 10.0, message: "Use UserNotifications Framework's -[UNUserNotificationCenter removeAllPendingNotificationRequests]")
> open func cancelAllLocalNotifications()
> ```

You will have to add this import statement,

```
import UserNotifications
```

Get notification center. And perform the operation like below

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.removeAllDeliveredNotifications() // To remove all delivered notifications
center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests() // To remove all pending notifications which are not delivered yet but scheduled.
```

If you want to remove single or multiple specific notification, you can achieve it by below method.

```
center.removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: ["your notification identifier"])
```

Hope it helps..!!

Comment: I implemented same. Thanks

Answer (score 19):

**For iOS 10, Objective C**:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
[center removeAllDeliveredNotifications];
[center removeAllPendingNotificationRequests];
```

**Swift 4**:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
```

If you want to list all notifications:

```
func listPendingNotifications() {

    let notifCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    notifCenter.getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler: { requests in
        for request in requests {
            print(request)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: if you get following error [UNUserNotificationCenter'; did you mean 'NSNotificationCenter'?], please, import UserNotifications in your source file, like so: #import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>

Comment: @marcelo dos santos .  This removes sending local notification for an application.  and again if user wants to turn on notification?  scheduledLocalNotifications will work.  please give example for turn on in objective-c.

Comment: @kiran, you should schedule again your notifications. I have a method that reschedule my whole events, because my goal is to ensure to my user always the most updated information.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 10, You can use this way for removing all of Local Notification.
I have just tested, It's working.

```
    NSArray *arrayOfLocalNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] ;
    for (UILocalNotification *localNotification in arrayOfLocalNotifications) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:localNotification] ;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not certain but it seems like this is NOT working on iOS10 SDK if you link to the new `UserNotifications`

Comment: scheduledLocalNotifications  is deprecated too https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622993-scheduledlocalnotifications?language=objc